# Can union of more than $2$ subspaces of a vector space be another subspace $?$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So  given  that  $V$  is  a vector  space and  $W_{1}$ and  $W_{2}$  are  two  proper  subspaces  of  $V.$

I  have  learnt  the  proof  that  $W_{1}\cup W_{2}$  is  a  subspace  of  $V$  iff  either  $$W_{1}\subseteq W_{2}$$  or   $$W_{2}\subseteq W_{1}$$  holds.

Now  here  is  my  question .  What  if  I  have  more  say$\ \ $  $3$ $\ \ $ or  even  more  proper  subspaces  of  $V$  and  their  union $\ \ \cup_{i=1}^{n} W_{i}\ \ $ is  there  a  similar  necessary  and  sufficient  condition
  for  their  union to  be  a  subspace  $?$
When  can I  say  that  $\ \ \cup_{i=1}^{n} W_{i}\ \ $   is  also  a  subspace of   $V$ $?$

I  can  see  that if  $$W_{1}\subseteq W_{2} \subseteq ......\subseteq W_{n}$$  (possibly  with  some  reordering )  holds  then $$\cup_{i=1}^{n} W_{i}$$  is  a  subspace .  But  can  I  prove  the  converse  i.e.  when $$\cup_{i=1}^{n} W_{i}$$  is  a  subspace  $$W_{1}\subseteq W_{2} \subseteq ......\subseteq W_{n}$$  (possibly  with  some  reordering ) must  hold $?$ I  mean  is  that  true  or  not  $?$

Comment: take $W_1 = \operatorname{span}(e_1)$, $W_2 = \operatorname{span}(e_2)$, and $W_3 = \operatorname{span}(e_1, e_2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Since we are taking our subspaces to be proper we'll consider $\mathbb R^4 = ${$(w,x,y,z)$} to be the $V$. Let $W_1$ be the subspace spanned by the $w$ axis, $W_2$ be the subspace spanned by $x$ and $y$ and let $W_3$ be the span of $w$, $x$ and $y$. Then the union of the three $W_i$s form a subspace that does not follow a subset ordering.